# A fractional Quantum Hall state is translational invariant on a Riemann sphere

Tags: condensed-matter, mathematical-physics, quantum-hall-effect

In [this note](http://wwwphy.princeton.edu/~haldane/talks/fdmhMAR08.pdf) (I guess presentation) which is about the relation between certain Jack polynomials and FQH states, Haldane states the following (paraphrasing slightly)

> Generic incompressible FQHE droplets covering an area $2\pi N_\Phi$ are described by
>   polynomial wavefunctions $f(z_1, \cdots, z_N)$ ($N$ number of particles) obeying both
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> &L^+f:=\left[\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}\right]f(z_1, \cdots, z_N)=0 && \text{highest weight condition}\\
> &L^-f:=\left[N_\Phi(z_1+\cdots, z_N)-\sum_{i=1}^N z_i^2\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}\right]f(z_1, \cdots, z_N)=0 && \text{lowest weight condition}
> \end{aligned}
> $$
>   This is the condition that *the state is translationally-invariant when put on the Riemannn sphere*.

In [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0711.3062v2) section II, Haldane & Bernevig furthermore say that

> Uniform states on the sphere satisfy the conditions $L^\pm \psi = 0$.

In the same paper the origin of why these condition are called highest/lowest becomes clear.

I'm looking for a reference for/proof of all of these facts:

- Generic incompressible FQHE droplets covering an area $2\pi N_\Phi$ are described by
  polynomial wavefunctions $f(z_1, \cdots, z_N)$ ($N$ number of particles) obeying $L^\pm f = 0$.
- The fact that the above condition is equivalent to saying the state is translationally-invariant when put on the Riemannn sphere.
- And finally an explanation of what is meant by "Uniform states on the sphere satisfy the conditions $L^\pm \psi = 0$." (I'm guessing the single particle density obtained from the respective wavefunction is uniform on the sphere?) and furthermore why does $L^\pm \psi=0$ imply this assertion?

One thing that I know is a polynomial $f$ satisfies the highest weight condition if and only if for all $c\in \mathbb{C}$ we have
$$
f(z_1+c, \cdots, z_N+c) = f(z_1, \cdots, z_N)
$$
This is not hard to prove with a simple Taylor explansion and this implies translational invariance over $\mathbb{C}$. It is not exactly clear to me what's the lowest weight condition is about however. Neither I know how the rest of the conclusions are made.